# How to get all the values using Xpath Selenium

Tags: testing, selenium, xpath, cucumber

I want to get all the values of td[3]. I have the below code

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
WebElement test;
test=driver.findElement(By.xpath("./" +value)); // here /*/*/td[5] is passed as param 
System.out.println("Values : " +test.getText());
```

I tried `/*/*/td[3]`  but it just gives me only the first value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//tr/td[3]
```

Returns each third `td` element, child of an `tr` element.

Comment: Sorry I just updated my code. but I am just getting the first element.

Comment: @Jay You are using `findElement`, which returns _one_ element. You should use `findElements` to get a list of elements.

Comment: ooh ok let me try that. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting an error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<WebElement> to WebElement"

Comment: @Jay Yeah, you have to iterate through the list.

Comment: Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: I don't know Java, but I'm sure you can find a lot of examples of *iterating a `List`*.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all data belonging to column 3 using following code:

```
 List <WebElement> allRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("\\table\\tr"));

 for(int i=0; i<allRows.size(); i++){

      WebElement col3Element = allRows.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("\td[3]"));

      System.out.println(" Row " + i "Columnn 3 data: " + col3Element.getText());

 }
```